# Getting values from JQuery Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently implementing a jQuery slider on a web-application and need to get the values from the slider to use in a Javascript function. For example if the user selects the range 100,000 to 450,000 to send min_value=100,000 and max_value=450,000 to a Javascript function.

How would I go abut this.

See below the code for my slider example.

```
    $(function() {
          $("#price_slider").slider({
            range: true,
            min: 50000,
            max: 1000000,
            step: 1000,
            values: [350000, 700000 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
              $( "#amount" ).val( "€" + ui.values[0 ] + " - €" + ui.values[1 ] );
              current_min_price: ui.values[0 ];
              current_max_price: ui.values[1 ]; 
            }
          });
          $( "#amount" ).val( "€" + $( "#price_slider" ).slider( "values", 0) + " - €" + $( "#price_slider" ).slider( "values", 1) );
        });
```

The slider looks as it should on the page, but I can't actually use it as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

```
current_min_price: ui.values[0 ];
current_max_price: ui.values[1 ];
```

Are these giving you JavaScript errors? If you want to assign variables you should use =

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking about. As [@DanielIgnat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27249855/) says, the below lines:

```
current_min_price: ui.values[0 ];
current_max_price: ui.values[1 ];
```

look wrong. What this does is create [code line labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#label_Statement) called *current_min[max]_price*, and evaluate the expressions `ui.values[0]` and `[1]` (which is the same as writing `100000;450000;` and should have no practical effect)

If `current_min_price` and `current_max_price` are variables, or properties on some object (that you should then access with `window.` or `obj.current_min_price`), you can set them with the [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) `=`:

```
current_min_price = ui.values[0];
current_max_price = ui.values[1];
```

---

This is the only bit that looks wrong in the posted question, the rest of your code looks ok. If this doesn't help, you might want to include more details.